# All of my Media Queries work except one

Tags: css, media-queries, margin

I have 4 images that exist on the page in a table format. As you resize the page, the table changes via `media queries`. It goes from all 4 in a row, to 3 in a row and 1 below, to 2 in a row with 2 below in a row, to 1 per row with 4 rows.

The following code works on the first two instances described (4 in a row and then 3) but not with the 2x2:

```
@media only screen and (max-width:631px){
  .resize-logo {width:350px;height:auto}
  .DBS-logo {margin-top:100px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;display:table}
  .allBanners {margin-top:100px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;display:table}
  .banner1 {margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;text-align:center;width:300px}
  .banner2 {margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;text-align:center;width:300px}
  .banner3 {margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;text-align:center;width:300px}
  .banner4 {margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;text-align:center;width:300px}
  .style1 {margin:auto;margin-top:100px;font-size:20px}
}

@media only screen and (min-width:632px) and (max-width:947px){
  .resize-logo {width:400px;height:auto}
  .DBS-logo {margin-top:100px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;display:table}
  .allBanners {margin-top:150px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;display:table}
  .banner1 {text-align:center;width:300px;display:inline-table;padding:5px}
  .banner2 {text-align:center;width:300px;display:inline-table;padding:5px}
  .banner3 {text-align:center;width:300px;display:inline-table;padding:5px}
  .banner4 {text-align:center;width:300px;display:inline-table;padding:5px}
  .style1 {margin:auto;margin-top:100px;font-size:20px}
}

@media only screen and (min-width:948px) and (max-width:1263px){
  .resize-logo {width:400px;height:auto}
  .DBS-logo {margin-top:100px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;display:table}
  .allBanners {margin-top:150px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;display:table}
  .banner1 {text-align:center;width:300px;display:inline-table;padding:5px}
  .banner2 {text-align:center;width:300px;display:inline-table;padding:5px}
  .banner3 {text-align:center;width:300px;display:inline-table;padding:5px}
  .banner4 {margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;text-align:center;width:300px;padding:5px}
  .style1 {margin:auto;margin-top:100px;font-size:20px}
}

@media only screen and (min-width:1264px){
  .resize-logo {width:400px;height:auto}
  .DBS-logo {margin-top:100px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;display:table}
  .allBanners {margin-top:200px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;display:table}
  .banner1 {text-align:center;width:300px;display:inline-table;padding:5px}
  .banner2 {text-align:center;width:300px;display:inline-table;padding:5px}
  .banner3 {text-align:center;width:300px;display:inline-table;padding:5px}
  .banner4 {text-align:center;width:300px;display:inline-table;padding:5px}
  .style1 {margin:auto;margin-top:100px;font-size:20px}
}
```

It still puts them into rows, 2 rows of 2 per row, however it doesn't center them to the center of the page like the rest of them. After `inspecting the element` I noticed that for the ones that do keep it center, the `width of the container` stays the same while the `margin` updates. For the one that doesn't work, the `width of the container` changes while the `margin` stays the same.

What is the issue?

**EDIT**

Here is the code of my page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Marketing</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="_/css/start.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="DBS-logo">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <img class="resize-logo" src="_/img/dbs_logo_dvd.png">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="allBanners">
<table class="banner1">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href="_/videos/100-Full-Rooms.mp4"><br>
        <img class="resize-movies" src="_/img/100_full_rooms.jpg">
      </a>
      <span class="style1">100 Full Rooms</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table class="banner2">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href="_/videos/About-DBS.mp4"><br>
        <img class="resize-movies" src="_/img/about_dbs.jpg">
      </a>
      <span class="style1">About DBS</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table class="banner3">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href="_/videos/In-the-Beginning.mp4"><br>
        <img class="resize-movies" src="_/img/in_the_beginning.jpg">
      </a>
      <span class="style1">In the Beginning</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table class="banner4">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href="_/videos/The-Power-of-Multiplication.wmv"><br>
        <img class="resize-movies" src="_/img/the_power_of_multiplication.jpg">
      </a>
      <span class="style1">The Power of Multiplication</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you should also add the HTML code

Comment: @johannes What HTML code?

Comment: ??? the code of your webpage!

Comment: @johannes Just put it up